# Tableview scrolling and header views

Tags: iphone

My application has a header (like toolbar) which contains some button controllers,and just below the header view there is a tableview which contains some datas from sqlite.

When the tableview starts scrolling, I need the top header to hide and another header to pop out in place of the main header view.

Is it possible to this? But I didnt want this in a tap function.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if(scrollView == table)
    {
        tab.contentOffset = table.contentOffset; 
        headerview.hidden=YES;
    }
    else
    {
        table.contentOffset = tab.contentOffset;
        headerview.hidden=YES;
    }
}
```

it hides the headerview ,but my problem is when the scrolling of tableview stops headerview need to be appear again.

Comment: Have you Tried UIsrollView delegate methods. UItableView is a subclass of UIscroll View.

Comment: @pawan.mangal ,how to do this with a scrollview deligate method?can u give me some breef idea for that

Comment: Have you Tried UIsrollView delegate methods. UItableView is a subclass of UIscroll View.but I have doubt UIScrollView delegate method will be notify in UIviewController or not. as it is handled by UITableViewDelegate.

Comment: @pawan.mangal - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
 if(scrollView == table)
 {
  tab.contentOffset = table.contentOffset; 
        headerview.hidden=YES;
 }
 else
 {
  table.contentOffset = tab.contentOffset;
        headerview.hidden=YES;
 }
}
this is my code ,it works fine ,when we scroll the table,it hides the view,but now my problem is when the scrolling done headerview need to be apper again.

Comment: @pawan.mangal i have got my answer,please chk my own answer.plz.

Comment: @ICoder what is tab here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"scrollViewDidEndDecelerating");
    if(scrollView == table)
    {
        tab.contentOffset = table.contentOffset; 
        headerview.hidden=NO;

    }
    else
    {
        table.contentOffset = tab.contentOffset;
        headerview.hidden=NO;

    }
}
```

when the scroling stops it

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if(scrollView == table)
    {
        tab.contentOffset = table.contentOffset; 
        headerview.hidden=YES;
    }
    else
    {
        table.contentOffset = tab.contentOffset;
        headerview.hidden=YES;
    }
}
```

it hidses the header view.
thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Use the property tableHeaderView for that.
In Interface Builder (or in a xib in XCode) put a empty UIView in the top of your table and put then your stuff into this view.

Comment: sir,i didnt understand your answer,can u expln it plzzzz.thanks

Comment: i put a view to the header section of the tableview but nothing happens